# Why does this C++ code compile when using clang -std=gnu++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

This compiles when using `clang -std=gnu++11 -c test.cpp`:

```
void test() {
    [[random text here]]
    if (0) {
    }
}
```

But this gives error `main.cpp:3:1: error: expected statement`:

```
void test() {
    [[random text here]]
}
```

If I compile with `clang -std=gnu++11 -S -emit-llvm main.cpp` and look at the LLVM code it looks like the `[[...]]` line has no effect:

```
define void @_Z5testv() nounwind uwtable ssp {
  ret void
}
```

Any ideas why? bug or some C++11 syntax or GNU extension syntax?

Im using clang from Xcode 4.4.1 (Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn).

Comment: `[[random text here]]` Is that a literal description of exactly what you put in the code, or is that a placeholder for something? I just want to clarify that.

Comment: no placeholder that is the exact source code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is using C++11's attribute syntax. "`random text here`" is therefore assumed to be an attribute. By the C++11 specification, an attribute can modify many statements and declarations.

Attributes can be statements, but they have to actually be *statements*. Meaning they end in a `;` just like many other C++ statements.

The set of attributes supported by an implementation is implementation-defined (and Clang doesn't support any. Indeed, it apparently isn't supposed to support attribute syntax at all, [according to the website](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)). Attributes not implemented by a particular implementation should be ignored, which is why it has no effect.

Comment: Thanks! I stumbled upon this in some Objective-C++ code where someone had accidentally typed `[[NSValue alloc]]` alone on a line :)

Comment: Clang does support C++11 attribute syntax, and even supports a non-standard attribute: [clang::fallthrough](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#clang__fallthrough). Clang does actually make some use of the standard attributes as well. For example it can produce a warning for a function marked `[[noreturn]]` that actually does return, and codegen is actually affected. I imagine that not everything is complete so it's not marked yet.

Comment: @bames53: That's odd, since their website simply says "no". Not even a partial or something.

Comment: @Nicol: The website doesn't talk about SVN stuff IIRC.